# Why in paper space of AutoCAD 3D are colors of object shade not displaying

Tags: autocad

I am using AutoCAD 2016. In model space, I draw a colored 3D object. Then I made an isometric view of that object in the paper space (layout page). In the 'Appearance' section of 'Drawing View Editor' I selected the 'Shaded with visible lines' option as below.

[image]

In spite of that, in the layout page, the shade of the object, and its color is not displaying.

I also make it confirm that in the 'Page Setup' window, the 'Display plot styles' checkbox is unchecked.

I did many things to have shade colors in layout, but nothing became successful.

Can anybody suggest me a solution?